# CORS Filter could not be found - jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I've been struggling with this problem for a long time now. It suddenly started and I have no idea how to fix it or what I did wrong. I've been stackoverflowing for a long time and didn't get anywhere. I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111074/jersey-rest-the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-class), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686608/jersey-resource-not-found) and many other links.
I wasn't working here when this dev environment was set up and never really worked with jersey before.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting:

```
Fev 28, 2014 4:55:00 PM com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices getInstances
SEVERE: The class <my_package>.jersey.ResponseCorsFilter could not be found. This class is ignored.
Fev 28, 2014 4:55:00 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
Fev 28, 2014 4:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>PACKAGE_PATH.ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>PACKAGE_PATH.controller,
                         PACKAGE_PATH.supin.controller,
                         PACKAGE_PATH.rth.controller,
                         PACKAGE_PATH.rtp.pgto.controller,
                         PACKAGE_PATH.dir.controller.bgt,
                         PACKAGE_PATH.kpi.dir.controller.pa</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And this is my ResponseCorsFilter.java:

```
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest req, ContainerResponse contResp) {
    ResponseBuilder resp = Response.fromResponse(contResp.getResponse());
    resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");

    String reqHead = req.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

    if(null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals("")){
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
    }

    contResp.setResponse(resp.build());

    return contResp;
}

}
```

This is one of the controllers. I call it by using `http://localhost:8081/CSI/rest/chart/pa/01012013/01012014/getPA`

```
@Path("chart/pa")
public class PAController {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{firstParam}/{secondParam}/getPA")
public Response GetPA(@PathParam("firstParam") String p1,
            @PathParam("firstParam") String p2) throws Exception {

...
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it and forgot to post the answer.

I was importing a WAR file from another developer. At first, it worked fine. But then, all of a sudden, it stopped. I realized I was missing the Jersey files on the build path. Since it worked for a while, I never thought it would start behaving like this.

I'm using Eclipse, so it was pretty easy:

> Project Explorer -> Right-click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Then:

> Add External JARs

Simple as that.